# Why a parameter is taken as a column name?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I have this dynamic query

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetEquipmentsAllData] 
   @Eq_IN VARCHAR(18) = ''
  ,@FromDate DATE = NULL
  ,@ToDate DATE = NULL
  ,@ServertableName VARCHAR(400)
AS
BEGIN
  IF (ISNULL(@servertableName, '') = '')
    SET @servertableName = '[Vail-PlantAdgas-Webservices]'

  DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(max)

  IF (@EQ_IN = '')
  BEGIN
    IF (
        @FromDate IS NULL
        AND @ToDate IS NULL
        )
    BEGIN
      SET @Sql = 'Select 
            distinct H.EQHeaderID,H.EQUNR ''Equipment No'', H.STTXT ''Description'', H.EQTYP ''Equipment Type'', 
            --H.DATAB ''Valid From'', 

            g.EQART ''Object Type'', g.HERST ''Manufacturer'', g.TYPBZ ''Model No'',  
            g.SERGE ''Manufacturer Serial No'', g.HERLD ''Manufacturer Country'', g.BAUJJ ''Construction Year'', g.BAUMM ''Construction Month'',

            loc.SWERK ''Maint Plant'', loc.STORT ''Location'', loc.BEBER ''Plant Section'',

            Org.BUKRS ''Company Code'', Org.ANLNR ''Asset'', Org.GSBER ''Business Area'', Org.KOSTL ''Cost Center'', Org.PROID ''WBS Element'',

            str.TPLNR ''Functional Location'', str.HEQNR ''Superior Equipment'', str.POSNR ''Position'', str.SUBMT ''Const Type''


            from  ' + @servertableName + '.dbo.EQ_Header h 

            left Join ' + @servertableName + '.dbo.EQ_General g
            ON h.EQHeaderID= g.HeaderID
            left Join ' + @servertableName + 
        '.dbo.EQ_Location loc
            ON loc.HeaderID= h.EQHeaderID
            left Join ' + @servertableName + '.dbo.EQ_Organizations org
            ON org.HeaderID= loc.HeaderID
            left Join ' + @servertableName + '.dbo.EQ_Structure str
            ON str.HeaderID= org.HeaderID
            --Left Join ' + @servertableName + '.dbo.Equipment eq
            --ON eq.EquipmentNo= h.EQUNR
            Where h.Status IS NULL OR Status NOT IN(1,3)'
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
      SET @Sql = 'Select 
            distinct H.EQHeaderID,H.EQUNR ''Equipment No'', H.STTXT ''Description'', H.EQTYP ''Equipment Type'', 
            --H.DATAB ''Valid From'', 

            g.EQART ''Object Type'', g.HERST ''Manufacturer'', g.TYPBZ ''Model No'',  
            g.SERGE ''Manufacturer Serial No'', g.HERLD ''Manufacturer Country'', g.BAUJJ ''Construction Year'', g.BAUMM ''Construction Month'',

            loc.SWERK ''Maint Plant'', loc.STORT ''Location'', loc.BEBER ''Plant Section'',

            Org.BUKRS ''Company Code'', Org.ANLNR ''Asset'', Org.GSBER ''Business Area'', Org.KOSTL ''Cost Center'', Org.PROID ''WBS Element'',

            str.TPLNR ''Functional Location'', str.HEQNR ''Superior Equipment'', str.POSNR ''Position'', str.SUBMT ''Const Type''


            from  ' + @servertableName + '.dbo.EQ_Header h 

            left Join ' + @servertableName + '.dbo.EQ_General g
            ON h.EQHeaderID= g.HeaderID
            left Join ' + @servertableName + 
        '.dbo.EQ_Location loc
            ON loc.HeaderID= h.EQHeaderID
            left Join ' + @servertableName + '.dbo.EQ_Organizations org
            ON org.HeaderID= loc.HeaderID
            left Join ' + @servertableName + '.dbo.EQ_Structure str
            ON str.HeaderID= org.HeaderID
            --Left Join ' + @servertableName + '.dbo.Equipment eq
            --ON eq.EquipmentNo= h.EQUNR

            Where h.Status IS NULL OR Status NOT IN(1,3) and
            h.EntryDateTime BETWEEN ''' + convert(NVARCHAR(20), @FromDate) + ''' AND ''' + convert(NVARCHAR(20), @ToDate) + ''''
    END
  END
  ELSE
  BEGIN
    IF (
        @FromDate IS NULL
        AND @ToDate IS NULL
        )
    BEGIN
      SET @Sql = 'Select 
            distinct H.EQHeaderID,H.EQUNR ''Equipment No'', H.STTXT ''Description'', H.EQTYP ''Equipment Type'', 
            --H.DATAB ''Valid From'', 

            g.EQART ''Object Type'', g.HERST ''Manufacturer'', g.TYPBZ ''Model No'',  
            g.SERGE ''Manufacturer Serial No'', g.HERLD ''Manufacturer Country'', g.BAUJJ ''Construction Year'', g.BAUMM ''Construction Month'',

            loc.SWERK ''Maint Plant'', loc.STORT ''Location'', loc.BEBER ''Plant Section'',

            Org.BUKRS ''Company Code'', Org.ANLNR ''Asset'', Org.GSBER ''Business Area'', Org.KOSTL ''Cost Center'', Org.PROID ''WBS Element'',

            str.TPLNR ''Functional Location'', str.HEQNR ''Superior Equipment'', str.POSNR ''Position'', str.SUBMT ''Const Type''


            from  ' + @servertableName + '.dbo.EQ_Header h 

            left Join ' + @servertableName + '.dbo.EQ_General g
            ON h.EQHeaderID= g.HeaderID
            left Join ' + @servertableName + 
        '.dbo.EQ_Location loc
            ON loc.HeaderID= h.EQHeaderID
            left Join ' + @servertableName + '.dbo.EQ_Organizations org
            ON org.HeaderID= loc.HeaderID
            left Join ' + @servertableName + '.dbo.EQ_Structure str
            ON str.HeaderID= org.HeaderID
            --Left Join ' + @servertableName + '.dbo.Equipment eq
            --ON eq.EquipmentNo= h.EQUNR
            where h.EQUNR= ' + @Eq_IN + ' and h.Status IS NULL OR Status NOT IN(1,3)'
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
      SET @Sql = 'Select 
            distinct H.EQHeaderID,H.EQUNR ''Equipment No'', H.STTXT ''Description'', H.EQTYP ''Equipment Type'', 
            --H.DATAB ''Valid From'', 

            g.EQART ''Object Type'', g.HERST ''Manufacturer'', g.TYPBZ ''Model No'',  
            g.SERGE ''Manufacturer Serial No'', g.HERLD ''Manufacturer Country'', g.BAUJJ ''Construction Year'', g.BAUMM ''Construction Month'',

            loc.SWERK ''Maint Plant'', loc.STORT ''Location'', loc.BEBER ''Plant Section'',

            Org.BUKRS ''Company Code'', Org.ANLNR ''Asset'', Org.GSBER ''Business Area'', Org.KOSTL ''Cost Center'', Org.PROID ''WBS Element'',

            str.TPLNR ''Functional Location'', str.HEQNR ''Superior Equipment'', str.POSNR ''Position'', str.SUBMT ''Const Type''


            from  ' + @servertableName + '.dbo.EQ_Header h 

            left Join ' + @servertableName + '.dbo.EQ_General g
            ON h.EQHeaderID= g.HeaderID
            left Join ' + @servertableName + 
        '.dbo.EQ_Location loc
            ON loc.HeaderID= h.EQHeaderID
            left Join ' + @servertableName + '.dbo.EQ_Organizations org
            ON org.HeaderID= loc.HeaderID
            left Join ' + @servertableName + '.dbo.EQ_Structure str
            ON str.HeaderID= org.HeaderID
            --Left Join ' + @servertableName + '.dbo.Equipment eq
            --ON eq.EquipmentNo= h.EQUNR
            where h.EQUNR= ' + @Eq_IN + '
            and Cast(h.EntryDateTime as Date) BETWEEN ''' + convert(NVARCHAR(20), @FromDate) + ''' AND ''' + convert(NVARCHAR(20), @ToDate) + '''
            and h.Status IS NULL OR Status NOT IN(1,3)'
    END
  END

  --Exec(@Sql)
  PRINT (@Sql)
END
```

Upon printing it is like this:

```
Select 
    distinct H.EQHeaderID,H.EQUNR 'Equipment No', H.STTXT 'Description', H.EQTYP 'Equipment Type', 
    --H.DATAB 'Valid From', 

    g.EQART 'Object Type', g.HERST 'Manufacturer', g.TYPBZ 'Model No',  
    g.SERGE 'Manufacturer Serial No', g.HERLD 'Manufacturer Country', g.BAUJJ 'Construction Year', g.BAUMM 'Construction Month',

    loc.SWERK 'Maint Plant', loc.STORT 'Location', loc.BEBER 'Plant Section',

    Org.BUKRS 'Company Code', Org.ANLNR 'Asset', Org.GSBER 'Business Area', Org.KOSTL 'Cost Center', Org.PROID 'WBS Element',

    str.TPLNR 'Functional Location', str.HEQNR 'Superior Equipment', str.POSNR 'Position', str.SUBMT 'Const Type'


    from  [Vail-PlantAdgas-Webservices].dbo.EQ_Header h 

    left Join [Vail-PlantAdgas-Webservices].dbo.EQ_General g
    ON h.EQHeaderID= g.HeaderID
    left Join [Vail-PlantAdgas-Webservices].dbo.EQ_Location loc
    ON loc.HeaderID= h.EQHeaderID
    left Join [Vail-PlantAdgas-Webservices].dbo.EQ_Organizations org
    ON org.HeaderID= loc.HeaderID
    left Join [Vail-PlantAdgas-Webservices].dbo.EQ_Structure str
    ON str.HeaderID= org.HeaderID
    --Left Join [Vail-PlantAdgas-Webservices].dbo.Equipment eq
    --ON eq.EquipmentNo= h.EQUNR
    where h.EQUNR= eq01
    and Cast(h.EntryDateTime as Date) BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2020-01-01'
    and h.Status IS NULL OR Status NOT IN(1,3)
```

It throws error when I pass parameters to it:

> **ERROR**: Invalid column name 'eq01'.

Parameters: 'eq01','2014-01-01','2020-01-01',''

Now I have tried many things to solve it but don't know what I am missing.

Comment: Please provide some sample data. Expected input/output.

Comment: why is `@Eq_IN` not inside string quotes?

Answer (score 0):

You have two instances of this clause in your code:

```
  where h.EQUNR= ' + @Eq_IN + '
```

The parameter is defined as a `VARCHAR(18)`, so when you reference it in dynamic SQL, you need to set it up so that the value will be wrapped in single quotes when the statement is evaluated. You do that by wrapping it in double single quotes in the dynamic query. The first single quote is the escape character for the second one.

So what the above instances should be:

```
  where h.EQUNR= ''' + @Eq_IN + '''
```

Without those quotes, the text is being evaluated as you have posted, where `eq01` is being treated as a column name, rather than as a text value.